# Question regarding the banning of a movie on-topic here?

Tags: discussion

I have question regarding the veracity of a movie being official banned in a certain country in the *past* and maybe still. Would that be on-topic here?

Or should I jump to movies.se or politics.se?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd be inclined to say yes, but with caveats. If neither the movie nor the censorship in question are particularly exceptional or historically significant, there's a very good chance the question would get closed for being mere trivia.

You should also be warned that I'm probably a lot more generous on what I consider on-topic than the average user on this stack.

To help you judge, here are a couple of examples of movie questions: [one that was successful](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/8923/what-is-adios-bruce-lee), and [one that was closed for being trivial](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/5656/did-the-fights-in-the-ip-man-movie-series-actually-occur-in-real-life).

Answer (score 1):

The value of a movie question basically depends on its links to wider historical events. On this site, we are interested in "history," but realize that it can be expressed in movie terms.

The question in T.E.D.'s example that was closed for being trivial (I voted to close) was one where the movie "misrepresented" history by presenting a lot of factual inconsistencies. This detracted greatly from its historical value, and led to the question being closed. The successful one was about how a movie represented larger events, such as how a popular American Kung Fu instructor was viewed in Latin America.

If you asked how a movie portrayed non-trivial historical events, e.g. a film that was banned in Saudi Arabia it was about a woman in a short sleeved dress driving a car after drinking vodka and eating pulled pork (all taboos in Saudi Arabia), that would be on topic.

Comment: The Bruce Lee question of mine was in fact a very interesting exemplar. I figured it was OK because Bruce Lee was a hugely influential pop culture figure. If you take Tom's logic for why it was OK, then only the information in *the answer* made it OK (since the questioner knew none of that). In the event the question did actually receive no few downvotes, and I think even a close vote or two, before that answer was posted. So it could be that Tom's dead on here.